# How C++ understands Array as pointers point of view?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I wrote the piece of code below but when I tried to return some two-dimensional array, it throws the following error.

```
    int (* function (int input[2][2]) ) [2][2]{

        return input;

    }
```

[image: gcc compiler error message]

from trial and error, I understand that when I change the function declaration to `int (* function (args) ) [2] {...}` it works like a charm, but why??? I don't understand. How C++ actually sees arrays? How these return declarations `int (* function () )[n][m]` actually works? What happens when I add another * to function declaration `int *(* function () )[n][m]` ??

My source for finding the solution to this problem was [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/declare-a-cc-function-returning-pointer-to-array-of-integers/) but I just copied some code and understood almost 0% of it.

It'll be nice if someone could explain to me how these work, and it would mean a world to me if you can suggest a good reading source for understanding these somewhat advanced notions in C++.

Comment: You have different types for the parameter and return type, there is an extra `*` in the return type

Comment: @M.M So I've figured, but I don't know how these pointer return types work overall.

Comment: "from trial and error..." - Don't learn C++ from trial and error. There are just too many incorrect things that can appear to work and you won't really understand things. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539). As far as I know, you simply can't return a plain array in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function declaration

```
int (* function (int input[2][2]) ) [2][2];
```

the argument of the array type is implicitly adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type. That is for example these function declarations

```
int (* function (int input[2][2]) ) [2][2];

int (* function (int input[100][2]) ) [2][2];

int (* function (int input[][2]) ) [2][2];
```

declares the same one function that is equivalent to

```
int (* function (int ( *input )[2]) ) [2][2];
```

So within the function the variable input has the pointer type `int ( * )[2]`. This pointer you are returning from the function

```
    return input;
```

So the function return type also must be `int ( * )[2]`. That means that the function must be declared like

```
int (* function (int input[2][2]) ) [2];
```

You could declare the parameter as having a referenced type. In this case you may return reference to the array.

```
int ( & function (int ( &input )[2][2]) )[2] [2];
```

Array types may not be used as the return type of function.

As for this declaration

```
int *(* function () )[n][m];
```

where n and m shall be constant expressions then the function returns pointer of the type `int * ( * )[n][m]`. For example the function can use an array name  declared within the function with the static storage duration something in a return statement like

```
static int * a[k][n][m];

//

return a;
```

So if you have an array as for example

```
T a[N1][N2][N3];
```

where `T` is some type and `N1`, `N2`, and `N3` its sizes then this declaration you may rewrite like

```
T ( a[N1] )[N2][N3];
```

Used in expressions the array (with rare exceptions) is converted to pointer to its first element. To declare such a pointer substitute the record in the parentheses to pointer like

```
T ( *p )[N2][N3] = a;
```